# Как правильно: употребить частицу Ж или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, поэзия

В данном стихотворении правильно написать с частицей Ж или без неё?

> Скоро будет 28,
>   Если доживу.
>   Зря Она невинных косит –
>   Я ДОСТОЙНЕЙ Ж, НУ:
>   Ничего себе не нажил
>   И другим не дал...

Comment: Чтобы следующее предложение начиналось с новой строки, поставьте два пробела в конце предыдущего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Послушайте, как звучит написанное: я... жну. Советую переставить *ж* в другое место:  "Я ж достойней, ну!"